# What is the difference between ^GSPC and ^SPX in yahoo finance?

Tags: options, yahoofinance, spx, sp500

I have understood that both display the same valute (S&P 500) but in ^SPX there are more option's data (more expiries).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that ^GSPC is Yahoo Finance's 'proprietary' ticker for the S&P 500 index. I have no idea why Yahoo Finance chose not to or was forbidden from using the common SPX ticker. It's worth noting that I have had reason to source the free daily, monthly or weekly ^GSPC data from Yahoo Finance a number of times over the years. As far as I can tell, the data is identical to historical SPX data, therefore I'm sure the tickers represent the same index.

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was no "^SPX" ticker on yahoo finance two three years ago (not very sure). So I guess "^GSPC" and "SPX" are the same, they just add "^SPX" to follow the most popular naming convention but still keep "^GSPC" for historical reason.

Answer (score 0):

Spx and spy are real tickers you can trade.
Gspc is not tradable
I hope it helps

Comment: @DStanley I don't think that SPX is the name of a tradable ticker - correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @rubikscube09 You are correct, I was thinking of SPY.

Comment: SPX is tradable via Index Options, @rubikscube09